# how to get distinct value for each table in a join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I'm building a database for event booking site. now I have EVENTS table that is related to one-to-many relation with (eventTickets, eventSponsors, eventGuests) TABLE.

```
CREATE TABLE EVENT (
           EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
           ORGANIZER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
          name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
          picture VARCHAR(50) NULL,
          venue VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
         city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT Ethiopia,
         sub_city VARCHAR(50) NULL,
         location VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        category VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
        start_date DATE NOT NULL,
        end_date DATE NOT NULL,
        longitude DOUBLE NULL,
        latitude DOUBLE NULL,
        status VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT DRAFT,
        discription TEXT NOT NULL,
       country VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL DEFAULT Ethiopia,
        end_time TIME NOT NULL,
       start_time TIME NULL,
       created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT TIMESTAMP(),
       PRIMARY KEY (EVENT_ID),
      FOREIGN KEY (ORGANIZER_ID) REFERENCES organizer(ORGANIZER_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

     ) ENGINE=INNODB;

     CREATE TABLE SPONSORS  (
           SPONSOR_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
           name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
          image VARCHAR(50) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (SPONSOR_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID) REFERENCES event(EVENT_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

     ) ENGINE=INNODB;



        CREATE TABLE GUESTS (
          GUEST_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
         first_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
         last_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        aka_name VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        title VARCHAR(15) NULL,
         bio VARCHAR(100) NULL,
        image VARCHAR(50) NULL,
        EVNT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (GUEST_ID),
       FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID) REFERENCES event(EVENT_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

     ) ENGINE=INNODB;

        CREATE TABLE EVENT_TICKETS (
            TICKET_ID INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            EVENT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
            name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            type VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
           price FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
           quantity INTEGER NOT NULL,
          discription VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
          sale_start DATE NOT NULL,
          sale_end DATE NOT NULL,
        active BOOL NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
        available INTEGER NOT NULL,
        created_on TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
        PRIMARY KEY (TIK_ID)
        FOREIGN KEY (EVENT_ID) REFERENCES event(EVENT_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE

     ) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

now I have the event table

```
      EVENT_ID | NAME
        1      | firstEvent
        2      | secondEvent
```

sponsor table

```
  SPONSOR_ID | EVENT_ID | name
       1     |    1      |    firstEventSponsor
       2     |    2      |   secondEventSponsor
```

guest table

```
GUEST_ID | EVENT_ID | first_name  | last_name
   1     |     1    |  firstEvent | guest
   2     |     2    |  secondEvent| guest
```

and ticket table

```
TICKET_ID | EVENT_ID | type  
   1     |     1    |  free  
   2     |     2    |  secondEvent
   3     |     1    |  paid
```

I want to get all of the related fields with a particular event from each of the other tables if a record exists or NULL if there is none. when I do a join I get a result set that repeats records of other tables until the largest return of the result set table row count match

HERE is my join

```
   SELECT  `event`.`EVENT_ID` AS 'eventId' ,`event`.`name` AS 'eventName' , `venue` `TICKET_ID` AS 'ticketId', `eventTicket`.`type` AS 'ticketType',
      `eventGuest`.`GUEST_ID` AS 'guestId',  CONCAT(`eventGuest`.`first_name`, " ", `eventGuest`.`last_name`) AS 'guestName', 
        `eventSponsor`.`SPONSOR_ID` AS 'sponsorId', `eventSponsor`.`name` AS 'sponsorName', 
    FROM `event`

    LEFT OUTER JOIN `eventTicket` ON `event`.`EVENT_ID` = `eventTicket`.`EVENT_ID`
    LEFT JOIN `eventGuest` ON `eventTicket`.`EVENT_ID` = `eventGuest`.`EVENT_ID`
    LEFT JOIN `eventSponsor` ON  `eventGuest`.`EVENT_ID` = `eventSponsor`.`EVENT_ID`

    WHERE `event`.`EVENT_ID` = 1
    GROUP BY `event`.`EVENT_ID`, `eventTicket`.`TICKET_ID`, `eventGuest`.`GUEST_ID`, `eventSponsor`.`SPONSOR_ID`    ;
```

this return a result set like this

```
eventId | eventName    | ticketId | type | guestId | guestName      | sponsorId       | sponsorName
   1    | firstEvent   | 1        | free | 1       |firstEventGuest | 1 | firstEventSponsor
   1    | firstEvent   | 2        | paid | 1       |firstEventGuest | 1 | firstEventSponsor
```

WHICH IS REPEATING ROWS OF EVENT GUEST AND EVENT SPONSOR RECORDS I WANT TO GET A RESULT SET THAT LOOK LIKE THIS IF ITS POSSIBLE

```
eventId | eventName    | ticketId | type | guestId | guestName      | sponsorId       | sponsorName
   1    | firstEvent   | 1        | free | 1       |firstEventGuest | 1 | firstEventSponsor
   1    | firstEvent   | 2        | paid | NULL       |NULL       | NULL  | NULL
```

I'm I using the wrong approach or is it the default please help I'm stuck with this challenge/

Comment: on the second row, your ticket ID is 2 but the type is paid?

Comment: Yeah that correct but guest id and sponsor id are represented,  i think this might be the default behavior.  If it is any workaround?

Comment: your guest table should have ticket id to determine which ticket the guest has.

Comment: Guest is related with event not ticket. They are special guests attending the event

Comment: then your guest id 1 will always be linked to ticket id 1 and 3 since those are associated with event id 1. are all records in guest table always be free (ticket id 1) unless it is for event id 2 (ticket id 2)?

Comment: It doesn't matter the type of ticket they are not related. Okay can you suggest any workaround i can do on the result set to filter the repeatations

Comment: your data says otherwise. i am asking these questions to solve your problem. your data says that guest is related to event and the same thing with ticket, then guest will be related to ticket. you have to determine how the guest id 1 will not be related to ticket id 3 but to ticket id 1 only.

Comment: yeah that the problem i dont have any distinguishing data between guest and ticket the only thing they have in common is they belong to the same event and have it's id as a foriegn key

Comment: this maybe a distinguishing factor to separate the data for ticket id 1 and ticket id 3, are all records in guest table always be free (ticket id 1) unless it is for event id 2 (ticket id 2)? let's say you have another row in guest table guest id 3 for event id 1, would that have the same result as this: eventId | eventName    | ticketId | type | guestId | guestName      | sponsorId       | sponsorName
   1    | firstEvent   | 1        | free | 3       |thirdEventGuest | 1 | firstEventSponsor

Comment: yes it the same

Comment: You *vaguely* say "get all of the related fields with a particular event from each of the other tables if a record exists or NULL if there is none." But what do you want returned when there are multiple records from multiple other tables for an event? Fill in the "..."s  in this: "Return (event_id,...) rows where (e.event_id, ...) in Event and event_id=e.event_id and ...". (First describe the result for when all 4 values exist. Find the key(s) of the result, and hence what sub-key values might repeat. You *will* get subrows repeating since the tables do not share a key. Later deal with NULLs.)

Comment: In a comment you say you want NULLs instead of certain repeated values--your question does not explain that. ("LIKE THIS"--*how*, "like"? What's that an example *of*?). And what orderings are relevant for columns & values when replacing erstwhile duplicates in columns by NULLs? What if there aren't 4 values to make a row? Are those rows left out before replacing duplicates in a column with NULL, or are there NULLs for that? Also, this formatting has surely been asked & answered before, so what (many) searches failed? Also more examples with more rows would help. PS Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

This will work on your sample data.

```
SELECT e.event_id AS 'eventId',
       e.name AS 'eventName',
       t.ticket_id AS 'ticketId',
       t.type AS 'ticketType',
       g.guest_id AS 'guestId',
       CONCAT(g.first_name, " ", g.last_name) AS 'guestName', 
       s.sponsor_id AS 'sponsorId',
       s.name AS 'sponsorName'
  FROM t_event e
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t_ticket t 
    ON e.event_id = t.event_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT *, CASE WHEN event_id = 1 THEN 1 ELSE event_id END ticket_id FROM t_guest) g 
    ON t.event_id = g.event_id AND t.ticket_id = g.ticket_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN t_sponsor s 
    ON g.event_id = s.event_id
 WHERE e.event_id = 1
 GROUP BY e.event_id, t.ticket_id, g.guest_id, s.sponsor_id;
```

Result (I've added guest id 3 sample data)

```
eventId eventName   ticketId ticketType  guestId guestName         sponsorId sponsorName
1       firstEvent  1        free        1       firstEvent guest  1         firstEventSponsor
1       firstEvent  1        free        3       thirdEvent guest  1         firstEventSponsor
1       firstEvent  3        paid        NULL    NULL              NULL      NULL
2       secondEvent 2        secondEvent 2       secondEvent guest 2         secondEventSponsor
```

Comment: Sorry but their is still ticketd 1 and sponsorid 1 repeated for event id 1. What i want is null on the repeated values place. I think its a dead end

Comment: as I said, I added guest id 3 sample data which is associated with event id 1. try the query to your database and see the result.